# How can I use navigator.clipboard.readText() in a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I wrote a Firefox extension that reads the clipboard and if it has some PEM certificate, it will print it's details in a new tab. I'm trying to port to Chrome. It does not work. What am I doing wrong?

I asked for the clipboardRead in manifest.json and I run this in background script and it works fine in Firefox.

```
 navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function (textFromClipboard) {
   //do stuff with textFromClipboard
 });
```

This fails in Chrome with "Failed to execute 'readText' on 'Clipboard': Illegal invocation". What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work in Chrome also? Most answers involve creating an input, getting focus, executing paste. That is really complicated, I hope I don't have to do this. It works really well in Firefox, why is it complicated in Chrome?

Comment: Don't know for within an extension, but Chrome allows the access to this API to mere scripts, as long as your request has been [*triggered by user activation*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation): https://jsfiddle.net/on905kw6/

Comment: See my comments here: [How do I prompt user for clipboard read permission in the popup of the chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/54325731)

Comment: So I cannot do it from the background script, right? Damn this really complicates things for me. Why does Chrome not support the nice clipboard API that Firefox supports in background scripts also? :(

Comment: Er? My point was you can probably do it by using the classic approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`@bumble/clipboard`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bumble/clipboard). It is an npm library for Chrome extensions that emulates the Clipboard API.

It doesn't require user interaction, and works in a background script. It only requires `clipboardRead` or `clipboardWrite` permissions.

```
import { clipboard } from '@bumble/clipboard'

// Read text from the clipboard, or "paste"
clipboard.readText()
  .then((text) => {
    console.log('clipboard contents', text)
  })

// Write text to the clipboard, or "copy"
clipboard.writeText('write this to the clipboard')
  .then((text) => {
    console.log(text, 'was written to the clipboard')
  })
```

*Disclosure: I wrote this library for myself to solve the same problems that @ddreian mentioned. It is a non-blocking Promise based solution that uses `document.execCommand` under the hood.*

Comment: This doesn't answer the question `What am I doing wrong? How can I make this work in Chrome also?` Also, your lib uses oldschool `document.execCommand` instead of wrapping the Clipboard API.

Comment: If the end goal was to use an API that *works* like the Clipboard API in a Chrome extension, this answer works. If the endgoal is to use the *actual* Clipboard API in a Chrome extension background page, then you're correct. In that case, there is no answer to this question, since the Clipboard API requires user interaction, which isn't possible in a Chrome extension background page.

Comment: @JackSteam your solution will not work on ManifestV3, cause is a service worker.

Comment: @titusfx Correct. This answer is for MV2. There is currently no way to use the Clipboard API in MV3, except in a HTML page, eg options or popup page.

Comment: The library [`@bumble/clipboard`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bumble/clipboard) is now a 404 in npm.

Answer (score 0):

add In your code (popup.js):

```js
navigator.clipboard.readText = function() {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea')
  document.body.appendChild(textarea)
  textarea.focus()
  document.execCommand('paste')
  const {value} = textarea
  textarea.remove()
  return value
}
```

dont forget about permissions in manifest:

```
"permissions": [ "clipboardRead" ],
```