# Chrome extension - set clipboard on click extension icon

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to achieve a simple action on a Google Chrome extension: when user is on a tab, it could click on the extension icon, and something (like a string) will be copied into its clipboard.

The only thing that I don't know how to deal with in this process is the copy action to the clipboard. Can you help me on this?

What I've done so far:
 - added the `clipboardWrite` permission to my `manifest.json`
 - added the `browser_action` section to my `manifest.json` to handle click on the icon extension
 - added something like this into my `background.js` file:

```js
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log(tab.url);
  const string = "something";
  // Here I need to add code to copy `string` to clipboard, looking for a way to do it
});
```

Any help on this would be useful :)

Comment: Use the standard approach, see [Using execCommand (Javascript) to copy hidden text to clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31593297)

Comment: I'm not working in a context of basic webpage. I don't understand how this can be a solution.

Comment: Simply use it, it Just Works. The background script runs in a hidden background page which is a standard DOM page.

Comment: No. That not works. I used another solution I will propose as answer. But your solution is not working.

Comment: It works for me and lots of other extensions so I guess you've used it incorrectly. Note that there are many answers in the topic I've linked. Here's a more generic one: [Copy to Clipboard in Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18455088)

Comment: Deleted my answer per wOxxOm's preference. Still, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386279/how-can-i-use-navigator-clipboard-readtext-in-a-chrome-extension/57327762#57327762